# How I can store sequential record id for an object in firebase

Tags: firebase

Right now when I push the json object to firebase it automatically created unique id for record like following.

```
Groups
    -JXZDad3udDvZ076RD__
        GroupDescription:  Test
        GroupName:  test
        Id: 1
    -JXZK8AVfxp6RyNMTaLQ
        GroupDescription: Another test
        GroupName: Simple
        Id: 2
```

**How I can make them (record id: -JXZDad3udDvZ076RD__) sequential like following.**

```
 Groups 
    1
        GroupDescription:  Test
        GroupName:  test
        Id: 1
     2
        GroupDescription: Another test
        GroupName: Simple
        Id: 2
```

Waiting for your help.

Comment: This is covered at length in the docs on [saving lists of data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-push)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You now add these objects to Firebase using something like:

```
var groups = [
  { GroupDescription: Test, GroupName: test, Id: 1 },
  { GroupDescription: Another test, GroupName: Simple, Id: 2 }
];
groups.forEach(function(group) {
  ref.push(group);
});
```

Using `push` tells Firebase to create a new child and automatically create a unique, ordered ID for you.

If you want to keep control of the name of the new children, you can simply specify your own `child` name and use `set`:

```
groups.forEach(function(group) {
  ref.child(group.Id).set(group);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the update using a promise returned by `.then()` after the `.push()` with `snapshot.key`:

```js
const ref = Firebase.database().ref(`/posts`);
ref.push({ title, categories, content, timestamp})
   .then((snapshot) => {
     ref.child(snapshot.key).update({"id": snapshot.key})
   });
```